# Linear algebra problem - how to prove this proposition

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$
  be a linear mapping. Assume that $\{\vec{v}_{1},\ldots,\vec{v}_{n}\}$
  is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
  such that $\{\vec{v}_{1},\ldots,\vec{v}_{k}\}$
  is a basis for $\ker(L)$
 . Prove that $\{L(\vec{v_{k+1}}),\ldots,L(\vec{v_{n}})\}$
  is linearly independent.

I'm trying to prove by contradiction, but I'm stuck on needing to prove $L$ is one-to-one over $\text{Span}\{\vec{v}_{k+1},\dots,\vec{v}_{n}\}$
 . Also, the proof is getting really long, so is there a better way to prove the proposition?

Comment: Take a linear combination. Use linearity of $L$. What is in the kernel of $L$ now?

Comment: I think I've seen this exact question 2 or 3 times already on this website. E.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/197927/35914

Comment: Another: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311369/l-mathbbrn-rightarrow-mathbbrm-is-a-linear-mapping-linear-independ

Comment: Yes, this question should be closed as a duplicate.